# Summarize hierarchical data with Linq to DB

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, hierarchical-data

I have a database that is represented(roughly) by the following structure. Note that since Entity Framework generates it, the GamePlayer class has the reference to a parent Game instance and GameAction class has the reference to a parent GamePlayer instance and corresponding Ids.

```
    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GamePlayer> Players { get; private set; }

    }
    public class GamePlayer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PlayerId{get;set;}
        public int GameId { get; set; }
        public Game Game { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GameAction> Actions { get; private set; }
    }
    public class GameAction
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ActionType ActionType { get; set; }
        public int? Amount { get; set; }
        public int GamePlayerId { get; set; }
        public GamePlayer GamePlayer { get; set; }
    }
    public enum ActionType
    {
        BET,
        FOLD,
        RAISE
    }
```

A single player can play multiple games and perform various actions.

I want to summarize the data to get the following statistic for each player:

- Number of games played
- number of bets made
- the sum of all bets made

For example:

| Player Name | Games | Bets | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 120 | 20 | 980 |
| Paul | 90 | 10 | 5 |
| Garry | 200 | 100 | 1500 |

The database contains thousands of players, millions of games, and even more actions.
Therefore, ideally, I would like to write a Linq request that runs on the server-side to prevent all the records from being loaded to the client.

Is it feasible? Or should I resort to stored procedures and pure SQL queries on the DB level?

Comment: Where is `PlayerId` coming from? Doesn't seem to match any of the shown entities / explanation, so I guess there must be `Player` entity / table, but how it is related to the shown entities?

Comment: @IvanStoev what difference does it make? Let's say that there is no such table. The list of players can be easily obtained by `db.Games.SelectMany(game=>game.Players).GroupBy(p=>p.Id).Select(gr=>gr.First())`

Comment: Because `GamePlayer.Id` doesn't seem to match "A single player can play multiple games". So basically in your sample model `GamePlayer.Id` is unique across all games, which makes the query trying to group by it useless, since 1 player plays 1 game. Please show the missing part of the model/relationships in order to see how to query it effectively.

Comment: @IvanStoev got it, edited

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting to see `Player.Games` navigation property as well, in order to try top-down LINQ query (w/o `GroupBy`) like `Players.Select(p => new { p.Name, Games = p.Games.Count(), ...}` vs bottom-up (with `GroupBy` as usual for SQL). What EF Core version are we targeting btw (since different EFC versions have different/no support for `GroupBy`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.1

Answer (score 2):

The desired LINQ query could be written in two ways - top-down without `GroupBy`, just following the naturally grouped data `Player` -> `GamePlayer` -> `GameAction`, or bottom-up `GameAction` -> `GamePlayer` and `GroupBy` (the traditional SQL way).

The first approach would generate many correlated subqueries (server side, but still), so probably it is better to follow the SQL way. Moreover EF Core 6.0 supports distinct count translation which is needed here to count the games duplicated by actions.

Here is the query which returns the data you want by `PlayerId`. You can always join it to `Player` in case you need other player info.

```cs
var query =
    from gp in db.Set<GamePlayer>()
    from ga in gp.Actions
    group new { gp, ga } by new { gp.PlayerId } into g
    select new
    {
        PlayerId = g.Key.PlayerId,
        Games = g.Select(e => e.gp.GameId).Distinct().Count(),
        Bets = g.Count(e => e.ga.ActionType == ActionType.BET),
        Amount = g.Sum(e => e.ga.ActionType == ActionType.BET ? e.ga.Amount : null),
    };
```

which for SqlServer is translated as

```sql
SELECT [g].[PlayerId], COUNT(DISTINCT ([g].[GameId])) AS [Games], COUNT(CASE
    WHEN [g0].[ActionType] = 0 THEN 1
END) AS [Bets], COALESCE(SUM(CASE
    WHEN [g0].[ActionType] = 0 THEN [g0].[Amount]
    ELSE NULL
END), 0) AS [Amount]
FROM [GamePlayer] AS [g]
INNER JOIN [GameAction] AS [g0] ON [g].[Id] = [g0].[GamePlayerId]
GROUP BY [g].[PlayerId]
```

which is very close to the what one would write in SQL.

Comment: thanks, that worked. One more trick is to calculate the number of Distinct games where a player made at least one bet(a player can bet multiple times in a single game). I tried `Bets = g.Select(e=>e.ga).Where(a => a.ActionType == ActionType.BET).DistinctBy(a=>a.GamePlayerId).Count()`, but it produces the ArgumentException. Am I missing something?

Comment: `DistinctBy` is new LINQ operator which I'p pretty sure is not supported by EF Core query translator. Probably you need  something similar to what I did for `Games` but with `Where` filter, e.g. `BetGames = g.Where(e => e.ga.ActionType == ActionType.BET).Select(e => e.gp.GameId).Distinct().Count()`